# A loop that doesn't work

Tags: android, loops

I'm trying to press a button just two times. To do that I try to insert a loop and then a disable, so the player can't press that button anymore. I don't understand why I can press the button just one time (show the card) and then the code will stop and the loop doesn't work. The value of the variable start from zero. I try to use also a for loop but the result is the same

```
final Button choice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.C);
            backgroundC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View view){
                    while (j < 2){  
                        int randomInt3 = random1.nextInt(Deck.length());
                        int drawableIDC = Deck.getResourceId(randomInt3, -1);
                        backgroundC.setBackgroundResource(drawableIDC);
                        j ++;
                }
                    choice1.setEnabled(false);
                }           
                });
```

Comment: Where and how is `j` declared ?

Comment: If you print some stuff, like `j`, you'll see that your code is not doing what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because: when you click, the loop will run (`2` times) and after it finishes, it will `disable` the button. What you need is the following code:

```
final Button choice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.C);
backgroundC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view){
        if (j < 2){  
            int randomInt3 = random1.nextInt(Deck.length());
            int drawableIDC = Deck.getResourceId(randomInt3, -1);
            backgroundC.setBackgroundResource(drawableIDC);
            j++;
        }
        else {
            choice1.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }           
});
```

Comment: you can remove else part, because if `j` became greater than 2 the code don't run

Comment: @shayanpourvatan when do you disable the button? You need to make sure when `j == 2` button gets disabled. The `else` is just a "neat" place to put this code.

Comment: why OP need to disable button? if `j == 2` then if statement not running so this like that button is disabled.

Comment: @shayanpourvatan yes. It will not work. Thats true. But the "visual" state is still enabled. Something like in the image:  http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-96z2MEV2chw/T1Bku6jCwlI/AAAAAAAAAXE/aP1MtOhc5Pg/s1600/button_enable_disable.jpg

Comment: yes you right, I couldn't see the link because this site is block in my country, but i get your mean

Comment: The `while` has been replaced with `if`.. please look carefully.